# How to make an html body transparent for UIWebView

Tags: html, uiwebview, transparent, scorm1.2

Hii....i am new to iPhone programming..Can anybody help me out please

i have an html which is generated by eXe tool.I need to show it on an UIImageView. so the html has to be transparent then the image looks like backround.

is it possible to make that html as transparent..?

Thank u

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just used [this](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9175823), and it worked fine. [UIColor clearColor] and [myWebView setOpaque:NO] are missing the square brackets, though. BTW, you can also set the background style in the html to an rgba value instead of totally transparent if you need, e.g. body { background:rgba(255,255,255,0.6); }

Comment: Great answer! You have to do both steps (clear and opaque). You can also uncheck Opaque and set the background as Clear Color from interface builder's attributes inspector.

Answer (score 1):

just write this line to become the UIWebView Transparent

```
[myWebView setOpaque:NO]
```